# Query troubling with joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am running the following query:

```
    select students.name, students.rollno, students.category as cat, `t1`.`studentid` 
    AS `studentid`,
    min(`t1`.`paperid`) AS `paper1`,
    min(`t2`.`paperid`) AS `paper2`,
    min(`t3`.`paperid`) AS `paper3`,
    min(`t4`.`paperid`) AS `paper4` from  students,
    ((((`sps` `t1` left join `sps` `t2` on(((`t1`.`studentid` = `t2`.`studentid`) and
    (`t2`.`paperid` > `t1`.`paperid`)))) left join `sps` `t3` on(((`t2`.`studentid` =
   `t3`.`studentid`) and (`t3`.`paperid` > `t2`.`paperid`)))) left join `sps` `t4`
    on(((`t3`.`studentid` = `t4`.`studentid`) and (`t4`.`paperid` > `t3`.`paperid`))))
    left join sgm on sgm.studentid=t1.studentid 
    left join str on str.studentid=t1.studentid 
    left join papers on t1.paperid=papers.p_id and papers.type='optional' 
    left join `students` `stu` on((`stu`.`studentid` = `t1`.`studentid`))) 
    where ((`stu`.`course` = '1') 
    and (`stu`.`status` = 'regular')
    and students.studentid=t1.studentid) 
    and papers.type='optional'  
    and sgm.groupid='1'
    and str.semesterid='1' 
    and str.sessionid='13' 
    group by `t1`.`studentid`  
    order by name
```

What I am trying to do here is , I am fetching results from tables :

```
Students Table
| studentid  |   name |    rollno   |  category |  course |
     1           ABC        1            new         1
     2           BCD        2            old         1
     3           CDE        3            new         1

Papers Table
|  p_id  |   p_name |  type |
    p1         a       main
    p2         b       optional
    p3         c       main
    p4         d       optional
    p5         e       optional

SGM
|  id  |  studentid  | group |
    1       1            a
    2       2            a
    3       3            b

SPS
|  id  |  studentid | paper |
    1        1          p1
    2        1          p3
    3        1          p4
    4        1          p5
    5        2          p3
    6        2          p4
    7        2          p5
    8        3          p1
```

These are the tables Students , SPS, SGM, Paper.
In the query what i am trying to find out is that there should be one result for each student which should have the information , name , rollno, cat , studentid, paper1, paper2,paper3 and paper4. I am able to do this but am stuck with getting only those paper whose type is optional. I need only optional paper to be selected. Type is in paperid and papers alloted to each student is in sps. How can i do that?

If there are no papers alloted, null value should be there.

Comment: . . If you want anyone to consider your question, format your query so it is readable.

Comment: tried a bit. See if its of any help

Comment: can you clarify this statement " I am able to do this but am stuck with getting only those paper whose type is optional. I need only optional paper to be selected"?

Comment: I am able to get every paper irrespective of their type. i need only those paper which have type 'optional' and other papers shouldn't be considered.